# Recursion, the stack and cache misses

Tags: c++, caching, memory

Imagine I need to traverse a tree. As I understand it, if I do it in a recursive way, each recursive function call would need to save its local parameters in a stack frame. The stack frame resides in stack memory, and each frame is pointed to by a stack pointer.

When does stack memory get loaded into the CPU cache? Each time the function returns? For example, if I am doing alot of recursive function calls, will it "trash" my CPU cache?

While traversing the tree, something done alot easier recursively (because of constraints on the data structures the function is dealing with) will I ever suffer alot of cache misses due to the stack alone?

The goal is try to minimize cache misses as much as possible while traversing the tree.

Comment: Go for tail-end recursion, then you can easily unroll it into a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

( Yea, yea, I know.  TLDR ;)

On a PPC I once worked on (I think it was the 860), there are two
cache's, data and code. (I think they were not in the CPU, but I
suppose where they reside does not matter.)

For a function call, that particular GCC compiler (your compiler
results may vary) generated code that

a) pushed the function parameters onto the stack of the called function, (i.e. parameter load)

and then

b) 'manipulated' the stack (pointer, typically a cpu register) to
establish the space for all outer scope automatic
variables (stack variables).  (Typically just by adding a simple
byte count to the stack pointer.)

NOTE: Both of these steps were completed *before* entering the
      function/method code.

Pushing the function parameters will cause some data cache to be
marked 'touched' (or is it still called dirty?), but how soon
that touched data actually gets to the stack memory is up to the
hw cache handler.

Function/method 'entry' (the jump to a new pc location) does
*nothing* to initialize the automatic variables, and this is the
programmers responsibility.  Thus, the data cache is unaffected
for them.

---

> When does stack memory get loaded into the CPU cache?

When stack data items are modified.  Data cache gets involved
when the code writes data to the stack.

> Each time the function returns?

No.

> each recursive function call would need to save its local
>   parameters in a stack frame

I think the function call sequence is more that the automatic
variables are already installed in the stack memory location, at a fixed compiler computed offset from the stack pointer, *before* the function starts running.  So when recursing (or calling any other function) the 'local' parameters are already in the stack, and thus already 'saved'.  There would be no additional save as part of the function call (or return).

Perhaps you are confusing "function call" with  "context
switch"? (where cpu registers must also be rolled out to ram)
Function calls are 2 to 3 orders of magnitude faster than context
switch because of this sudo 'register swap' and other os actions.

> For example, if I am doing alot of recursive function calls,
>   will it "trash" my CPU cache?

Not sure what you mean by 'trash' a cache.  (see also, my last paragraph below)  I would guess you are thinking about cache block sizes and potentially triggering
additional cache block write somehow.  And since you mentioned
recursion, maybe you are worrying that a recursive algorithm would
be more prone to such a thing.

The variety of cache complexity, and cache block sizes means your only
approach is to test.

However, to me, such concerns smacks of pre-mature optimization.
If the recursion is fast enough, if it meet the requirement, why
would you look into it.

As an example, I have some code where the recursive approach is
faster than the loop implementation (as well as being more
readable).  And when you can achieve tail recursion, you need not
bother to manually recode and retest. "-O3" optimization has
completely removed the stack use.  (Easily tested.)

> While traversing the tree, something done alot easier
>   recursively (because of constraints on the data structures the
>   function is dealing with) will I ever suffer alot of cache
>   misses due to the stack alone?

Personally, I enjoy recursion. If your problem is 'easier' to
read and understand using recursion, than you should use it. I
value readability most.  How else might you determine correctness.

---

On that embedded PPC I mentioned before, I could enable / disable both data cache  and instruction cache from the command line.

I expected instruction cache to provide a good performance boost,
and I was not dissapointed

I had lower expectations for data cache, and was quite surprised
at the magnitude.  The code I was working on at the time had
little recursion, no trees, no big file system.

You might find it interesting that some of my measurements showed
that small functions could return from the call before the preloaded parameters would make the journey from data cache out to ram.
That data cache ran with 0 wait states. The function "parameter load" was
cheap with respect to cache.

Comment: In re-reading this today, I feel I I should have emphasized that your questions and my answers are implementation dependent, not part of the language, but something worth knowing.  One topic you might research is the ABI (Application Binary Interface) for your target and tools  (i.e. ubuntu 64, g++ v5.2.1-23).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the stack is not loaded completely into the cache, instead it loads just the cache line which is needed. The processor does not know which memory belongs to your stack, it just sees memory addresses and cache lines.

So it will not trash your cache. Exact predictions are hard to make. Especially if you use non-trival destructors.

If you use [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) you compiler will optimize the code and in some cases the stack is removed when the recursive call is done - so only one stack is stored at all times.

Some wise people say: preemptive optimization is the root of all evil.